# Lambert cylindrical projection support in PostGis

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, spherical-geometry, lambert-conformal-conic

Does PostGis support Lambert cylindrical projection or is there a way to add support for it? I'm probably searching the wrong terms, but google isn't bringing up anything useful. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: if not Lambert, are there are other cylindrical equal-area projections which can be used in PostGis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's built in.**  [POSTGis](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/) uses the [Proj.4 library](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) for projections.  The source code for Lambert equal area is PJ_cea.c (in version 4.7.0); a better-documented version appears as cea.js in [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) version 1.0.2.  Here is the header from the .js version:

```
NAME                    LAMBERT CYLINDRICAL EQUAL AREA

PURPOSE:    Transforms input longitude and latitude to Easting and
        Northing for the Lambert Cylindrical Equal Area projection.
                This class of projection includes the Behrmann and 
                Gall-Peters Projections.  The
        longitude and latitude must be in radians.  The Easting
        and Northing values will be returned in meters.
```

---

Let's get back to your [original problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13435/get-relative-north-aligned-point-2163-us-equal-area), because we may have lost sight of it during the intervening questions:

> Basically I'm generating a grid table. Then I'll be doing a join query on some points and the grid table and group them by the cell they fall into to create histograms.

**You can do this easily without generating any grid at all,** because the formulas for an equal-area rectangular grid in decimal degrees are simple:

Let the intended width be *w* and the desired area be *A*.  On the plane, a rectangle's height would nominally be *h* = *A* / *w*.  Once and for all, convert *w* and *h* from meters to decimal degrees, using a conversion of approximately 10,000,000/90 meters per degree.  Suppose the grid's origin (lower left corner) is at (x0,y0) as longitude and latitude.  To determine what grid cell a point with (lon,lat) equal to (x,y) would fall in,

1. Compute x-x0 (as decimal degrees) and divide this by *w*.  Round the result up to the nearest integer: this is the grid column index, *j*.
2. Compute sin(y)-sin(y0) and divide by h.  Round up to the nearest integer: this is the grid row index, *i*.

The ordered pair (i,j) identifies the grid cell: use this to bin the points in the histogram.  It won't enable you to draw a picture of the grid, but maybe you don't need that for your analysis...

Comment: Great answer! I do need to draw the grid though.